# How to implement Front Controller Pattern in Android

Tags: android, front-controller

I am just learning Android, and I am trying to implement a Front Controller. 
I am using a Class which extends from BroadCastReceiver as a Front Controller:

```
public class FrontControllerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {}
```

In this way, every time an Activity needs to start another Activity, or start a Service, or a Service needs to send a response, I send a broadcast. This broadcast is received by the Front Controller and it decides what to do. 
What I need to know is whether this is a good programming practice, because I do think is not efficient. 
What would be the suggestion to efficiently implement the Front Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the definition for Front Controller on Wikipedia - `The pattern relates to the design of web applications.` Android isn't a web application, it has its own framework and expected usage patterns. While using a Mediator may work for certain aspects once you know what you are doing, I would delay trying to enforce 'good' design practice until you get a handle on the existing Android framework.